# Overriding code-generated DbContext constructor

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, connection-string

I'm sure I've done this before at some stage, but I can't figure out how to now! My scenario:

```
// This is generated from EDMX
public partial class HOLDbEntities : DbContext
{
    public HOLDbEntities()
            : base("name=HOLDbEntities")
        {
        }
}
```

Now, I want this connection string to be easily changeable (I want to Implement from the HOLDbEntities), so I need to override this constructor.

I've tried:

```
public partial class HOLDbEntities
{
    private const string _contextName = "HOLDbEntities";
    public static string ContextName { get { return _contextName; } }

    public HOLDbEntities()
        : base(ContextName)
    {
    }
}
```

But this throw an error:

> HOLDbEntities already defines a member called "HOLDbEntities" with the same parameter types.

I can understand why this errors, but how would I stop the constructor being auto-generated in the first place in order to do what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: Partial classes are parts of the same class so there's no way to have two or more methods (including constructor) with the same signature. In given example you can remove constructor in generated partial class (_note:_ if you regenerate entity, your changes will be lost) or overload constructor (e.g. `public HOLDbEntities(string contextName)
            : base(contextName)`).

Comment: I would simply add another constructor with the parameter you need so that both exist and in your calling code you decide which one to use

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best I can suggest is a factory method:

```
private HOLDbEntities(string contextName) : base(contextName) { }

public static HOLDbEntities Create() {
    return new HOLDbEntities(ContextName);
}
```

and use `HOLDbEntities.Create()` rather than `new HOLDbEntities()`.

Comment: This seems very elegant to what I'm trying to achieve, I'll give it a shot now and see if it works!

Comment: Works fine, but Unity is now complaining that the context cannot be constructed with a String value. Any way around this? Your answer is correct for my scenario anyway.

Comment: in MSDN it says DbContext constructor overriding with a string Constructs a new context instance using the given string as the name or connection string for the database to which a connection will be made. - can you please you explain it to me clearly or give me an example or reference. i did not find any good result while searching for it :(

Answer (score 21):

I up-voted the previous accepted answer because it is a fairly elegant way of doing it. However another approach would be to modify the T4 template that generates the dbContext Class.

When using EF DB first you have a .edmx file and under that you have an [Entity].Context.tt file. Go into that file and remove (or modify) the following code:

```
public <#=code.Escape(container)#>()
        : base("name=<#=container.Name#>")
    {
<#
if (!loader.IsLazyLoadingEnabled(container))
{
#>
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
<#
}

foreach (var entitySet in container.BaseEntitySets.OfType<EntitySet>())
{
    // Note: the DbSet members are defined below such that the getter and
    // setter always have the same accessibility as the DbSet definition
    if (Accessibility.ForReadOnlyProperty(entitySet) != "public")
    {
#>
        <#=codeStringGenerator.DbSetInitializer(entitySet)#>
<#
    }
}
#>
```

now your context class will generate without a constructor, so you should be able to go and create one in an extended class.

Comment: Won't the T4 code also get regenerated if you, say, drag another table onto the designer?

Comment: @AvrahamSeff nope, the t4s stay the same, and generate .cs files. any changes to the .cs files would get overrwitten in the way that you describe, but this is a change to the file that is doing the generating.

Comment: @as9876 the T4 code includes generic code that iterates over the entity types, so it doesn't need to be regenerated when new entity types are added

Comment: If you're going to edit the T4 template, then why not just modify the constructor there instead of removing it and adding another partial class?

Answer (score 3):

i changed the context.tt as follows:

```
<#=Accessibility.ForType(container)#> partial class <#=code.Escape(container)#> : DbContext
{
    public <#=code.Escape(container)#>()
        : base("name=<#=container.Name#>")
    {

<#
if (!loader.IsLazyLoadingEnabled(container))
{
#>
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
<#
}
foreach (var entitySet in container.BaseEntitySets.OfType<EntitySet>())
{
    // Note: the DbSet members are defined below such that the getter and
    // setter always have the same accessibility as the DbSet definition
    if (Accessibility.ForReadOnlyProperty(entitySet) != "public")
    {
#>
        <#=codeStringGenerator.DbSetInitializer(entitySet)#>
<#
    }
}
#>
var Method = (typeof(Entities)).GetMethods(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "OnModelConstructed");
if (Method!=null) Method.Invoke(this,null);
    }
```

so i can declare a **OnModelConstructed** method in a partial class of the context.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to the problem.  I edit the TT file as Dylan Hayes suggested and replaced the constructor with my own.  In my case, i needed to change the schema names of certain schemas only.  I set a variable in the config file to tell me what environment I was in and used the right schema.

```
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Xml;

namespace WS.Framework.WSJDEData
{

    public partial class WSJDE : DbContext
    {
        public WSJDE()
            : base("name=WSJDE")
        {
            ObjectContext context = (this as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;

            string environment = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Environment");

            const string devCTL = "TESTCTL";
            const string devDTA = "TESTDTA";
            const string qaCTL = "CRPCTL";
            const string qaDTA = "CRPDTA";
            const string prodCTL = "PRODCTL";
            const string prodDTA = "PRODDTA";

            var x = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("WSJDEData.WSJDE.ssdl");

            XmlReader[] sReaders = new XmlReader[]
                {
                    XmlReader.Create(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("WSJDEData.WSJDE.ssdl"))
                };

            XmlReader[] mReaders = new XmlReader[]
                {XmlReader.Create(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("WSJDEData.WSJDE.msl"))};

            StoreItemCollection sCollection = new StoreItemCollection(sReaders);

            ObjectContext objContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter) context).ObjectContext;
            MetadataWorkspace workspace = objContext.MetadataWorkspace;

            EdmItemCollection cCollection = workspace.GetItemCollection(DataSpace.CSpace) as EdmItemCollection;


            StorageMappingItemCollection csCollection = new StorageMappingItemCollection(cCollection, sCollection,
                                                                                         mReaders);

            workspace.RegisterItemCollection(sCollection);
            workspace.RegisterItemCollection(csCollection);

            EntityContainer container = workspace.GetItem<EntityContainer>("WSJDEModelStoreContainer", DataSpace.SSpace);

            foreach (EntitySetBase entitySetBase in container.BaseEntitySets)
            {
                string schema = entitySetBase.Schema;

                if (schema != null)
                {
                    string name = schema.Substring(schema.Length - 3);

                    if (name == "CTL")
                    {
                        switch (environment)
                        {
                            case "Dev":
                                typeof (EntitySetBase).GetField("_schema",
                                                                BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
                                                      .SetValue(entitySetBase, devCTL);
                                break;
                            case "QA":
                                typeof (EntitySetBase).GetField("_schema",
                                                                BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
                                                      .SetValue(entitySetBase, qaCTL);
                                break;
                            case "Prod":
                                typeof (EntitySetBase).GetField("_schema",
                                                                BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
                                                      .SetValue(entitySetBase, prodCTL);
                                break;

                        }
                    }

                    if (name == "DTA")
                    {
                        switch (environment)
                        {
                            case "Dev":
                                typeof (EntitySetBase).GetField("_schema",
                                                                BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
                                                      .SetValue(entitySetBase, devDTA);
                                break;
                            case "QA":
                                typeof (EntitySetBase).GetField("_schema",
                                                                BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
                                                      .SetValue(entitySetBase, qaDTA);
                                break;
                            case "Prod":
                                typeof (EntitySetBase).GetField("_schema",
                                                                BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
                                                      .SetValue(entitySetBase, prodDTA);
                                break;

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the string interpolations feature of C# 6 in the `.tt` code generation file.
The generated code becomes

```
public MyEntities()
            : base($"name={MyConfigurationManager.ConnectionStringKey("MyEntities")}")
{
}
```

when you use

```
public <#=code.Escape(container)#>()
    : base($"name={MyConfigurationManager.ConnectionStringKey("<#=container.Name#>")}")
```

in the `.tt` file.

`public static string ConnectionStringKey(string key)` in static class `MyConfigurationManager` in my case adds the initials of the login to the key and checks whether any connection string in `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` has that key in which case that key is returned and otherwise just returns the default key.

So now the connectionstring may be different per-user.
E.g.

```
<add name="MyEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Base.csdl|res://*/Base.ssdl|res://*/Base.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=localhost;initial catalog=local.base;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
<add name="MyEntitiesFB" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Base.csdl|res://*/Base.ssdl|res://*/Base.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=localhost;initial catalog=local.fb.base;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

means that user F.B. uses the latter key while all others the former key.