# dbcontext overriding code generated dbcontext constructor - follow up

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

In the previous post below:

[Overriding code-generated DbContext constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15088426/dbcontext-overriding-code-generated-dbcontext-constructor)

it suggested removing the constructor from the T4 Template and said:

"now your context class will generate without a constructor, so you should be able to go and create one in an extended class."

I cannot figure out how to create the extended class.

Before I edited the TT file, it created this:

```
public partial class WSJDE : DbContext
{
    public WSJDE()
        : base("name=WSJDE")
    {
    }
```

How do I create an extended class for this....

Thanks,

Patrick

****** Update

Tried this and it didn't work:

Created new file, WSJDE.cs and add this:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
namespace WS.Framework
{
    public partial class WSJDE : DbContext
    {
        public WSJDE()
            : base("name=WSJDE")
        {
        }
    }
}
```

For each entity in EF it sends this error:
Error   1   'WS.Framework.WSJDE' does not contain a definition for 'AddressBooks' and no extension method 'AddressBooks' accepting a first argument of type 'WS.Framework.WSJDE' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\Code\Trunk\WS\WS.Framework\ServicesInterfaceImplementation\AddressBookService.cs 15  47  WS.Framework

Comment: Create a new file (called WSJDE.cs or something unique) and put that code snippet in it.

Comment: Tried that, doesn't work.using System.Data.Entity;

namespace WS.Framework
{
    public partial class WSJDE : DbContext
    {
        public WSJDE()
            : base("name=WSJDE")
        {
        }
    }
}

Comment: `doesnt work` isnt especially useful. *how* does it not work? what error message do you get; what happens

Comment: For every object in EF it is giving this error:

Comment: 'Error 1 'WS.Framework.WSJDE' does not contain a definition for 'AddressBooks' and no extension method 'AddressBooks' accepting a first argument of type 'WS.Framework.WSJDE' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Code\Trunk\WS\WS.Framework\ServicesInterfaceImplementation\AddressBookService.cs 15 47 WS.Framework
'

Comment: what namespace is your generated class in? your partial class should be in the same namespace as the generated class. (you have it as `namespace WS.Framework`)

Comment: It was in the wrong namespace!!!  Thanks!

Comment: i can add it as an answer if you want so you can accept it ?